# Recording/Playback Gesture in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, record, gesture

I've done a bit of searching and I don't think this has been asked yet (if it has, then I have been searching with the wrong terminology)

I'm trying to find out how to record touch gestures/actions done on Android touchscreen (with respect to time), then use the path of that gesture as the path for a graphic to follow (using android's tweening capabilities)

I'm also looking to be able to save the animation so that it can be loaded later on or exported as a file.

My thoughts around this are to take the point of touch's (x,y) coordinates and save the pair across a set interval of time. Then the coordinates can be loaded from the file later on for an ImageView (or some other view) to be tweened across the device.

Plus, I figure a method like this could make it cross-compatible on screens of different sizes if I saved the coordinates as percents instead of actual values, they can then be loaded depending on the screen size of the device

My questions are: Am I on the right track? Or would this be an inefficient way of doing it?

If this is the right idea, what is the best way of recording the positions and then using the tweening capabilities to animate the object (or is there a better method than tweening to provide a smooth animation)?

And if not, what would be the suggested solution to my problem?

All answers appreciated!

Bitwize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool to record gestures in the devloper application examples. You can find on the emulator : GestureBuilder.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html) about gestures.

---

Though, gestures have been provided to be recognized as gestures not like an animation path. But I believe you can extract data from gestures and get the "path" of given single touch gesture. Here is the main class to represent a [gesture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/Gesture.html).

It has a `toPath()` method that could be useful to you.

Comment: Oh, awesome!
I was aware of Gesures in general, but I thought that it simply recognized similar shapes. I didn't know the path could be extracted like that; I think I way over-complicated things.
Would the path return the exact same dimensions as the original drawn gesture? And would it also be scalable so it can be used between devices of differing resolutions?

Comment: yes of course, sorry. Just out of curiosity though, can the path work with Android's tweening, or would that require a different method to animate the direction? And does the path actually record against time as well? reason I ask, is I would like for someone to draw/do something on the screen, and then have it play back exactly as it was done (so if they paused for a second, that would be included as well). Would it account for that?

Comment: I can't say. I never tried :) My guess is that timing won't be included, but really I would be happy to be wrong. You should just give it a try. That would be a nice demo app for gestures by the way.

Comment: GestureOverlayView gestures.addOnGestureListener, you can save the event point coordinates

Comment: But how about animating? Is there  any demos saving and showing the playback of the touch path?